# slicing sparse (scipy) matrix

Tags: python, scipy, slice, sparse-matrix, submatrix

I would appreciate any help, to understand following behavior when slicing a lil_matrix (A) from the scipy.sparse package.

Actually, I would like to extract a submatrix based on an arbitrary index list for both rows and columns.

When I used this two lines of code:

```
x1 = A[list 1,:]
x2 = x1[:,list 2]
```

Everything was fine and I could extract the right submatrix.

When I tried to do this in one line, it failed (The returning matrix was empty)

```
x=A[list 1,list 2]
```

Why is this so? Overall, I have used a similar command in matlab and there it works.
So, why not use the first, since it works? It seems to be quite time consuming. Since I have to go through a large amount of entries, I would like to speed it up using a single command. Maybe I use the wrong sparse matrix type...Any idea?

Comment: what does list1 and list2 contents ?  What gives A[list1:list2]  ??

Comment: list1 and list 2 are are python list objects containing integers e.g. [1,4,6,8]
A[list1:list2] is empty (<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>' with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>

Answer (score 17):

The method you are already using,

```
A[list1, :][:, list2]
```

seems to be the fastest way to select the desired values from a spares matrix. See below for a benchmark.

However, to answer your question about how to select values from arbitrary rows and columns of `A` *with a single index*,
you would need to use so-called ["advanced indexing"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
A[np.array(list1)[:,np.newaxis], np.array(list2)]
```

With advanced indexing, if `arr1` and `arr2` are NDarrays, the `(i,j)` component of `A[arr1, arr2]` equals

```
A[arr1[i,j], arr2[i,j]]
```

Thus you would want `arr1[i,j]` to equal `list1[i]` for all `j`, and
`arr2[i,j]` to equal `list2[j]` for all `i`.

That can be arranged with the help of [broadcasting](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) (see below) by setting
`arr1 = np.array(list1)[:,np.newaxis]`, and `arr2 = np.array(list2)`.

The shape of `arr1` is `(len(list1), 1)` while the shape of `arr2` is
`(len(list2), )` which broadcasts to `(1, len(list2))` since new axes are added
on the left automatically when needed.

Each array can be further broadcasted to shape `(len(list1),len(list2))`.
This is exactly what we want for 
`A[arr1[i,j],arr2[i,j]]` to make sense, since we want `(i,j)` to run over all possible indices for a result array of shape `(len(list1),len(list2))`.

---

Here is a microbenchmark for one test case which suggests that `A[list1, :][:, list2]` is the fastest option:

```
In [32]: %timeit orig(A, list1, list2)
10 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit using_listener(A, list1, list2)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.29 s per loop

In [33]: %timeit using_advanced_indexing(A, list1, list2)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.8 s per loop
```

---

Here is the setup I used for the benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import random
random.seed(1)

def setup(N):
    A = sparse.rand(N, N, .1, format='lil')
    list1 = np.random.choice(N, size=N//10, replace=False).tolist()
    list2 = np.random.choice(N, size=N//20, replace=False).tolist()
    return A, list1, list2

def orig(A, list1, list2):
    return A[list1, :][:, list2]

def using_advanced_indexing(A, list1, list2):
    B = A.tocsc()  # or `.tocsr()`
    B = B[np.array(list1)[:, np.newaxis], np.array(list2)]
    return B

def using_listener(A, list1, list2):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592783/190597 (listener)"""
    B = A.tocsr()[list1, :].tocsc()[:, list2]
    return B

N = 10000
A, list1, list2 = setup(N)
B = orig(A, list1, list2)
C = using_advanced_indexing(A, list1, list2)
D = using_listener(A, list1, list2)
assert np.allclose(B.toarray(), C.toarray())
assert np.allclose(B.toarray(), D.toarray())
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems quite elegant, but keep in mind that I am using a sparse matrix from the scipy.sparse package. Unfortunatelly, this kind of indexing does not work. It gives an IndexError.

Comment: Hm. Indeed, it does not work with `lil_matrix`, but it does work with `csc_matrix` or `csr_matrix`.

Comment: It seems to me that something like `A[list1,:][:,list2]` gives the same result but operates much faster on sparse matrices.

Comment: @unutbu, please consider including my new answer to this topic in your answer as you did with listener's solution.

Comment: @yogabonito: Thanks for your comment. Upon re-benchmarking the available options, it seems @passerby51 is right. `A[list1, :][:, list2]` is much faster than `A[np.array(list1)[:,np.newaxis], np.array(list2)]` or `A.tocsr()[list1, :].tocsc()[:, list2]`. I've edited my answer accordingly. I'd be interest to know if `A[list1, :][:, list2]` is not the fastest option on your machine for your setup.

Comment: @unutbu: You're right :) +1 for taking indexing with `[list1, :][:, list2]` into account. Just updated my answer to include the `%timeit`-results for this solution too.

Answer (score 4):

for me the solution from unutbu works well, but is slow.

I found as a fast alternative,

```
A = B.tocsr()[np.array(list1),:].tocsc()[:,np.array(list2)]
```

You can see that row'S and col's get cut separately, but each one converted to the fastest sparse format, to get index this time.

In my test environment this code is 1000 times faster than the other one.

I hope, I don't tell something wrong or make a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Simultaneous indexing as in `B[arr1, arr2]` does work and it's faster than [listener's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592783/7411135) on my machine. See `In [5]` in the Jupyter example below. To compare it with the mentioned answer refer to `In [6]`. Furthermore, my solution doesn't need the `.tocsc()` conversion, making it more readable IMO.

Please note that for `B[arr1, arr2]` to work, `arr1` and `arr2` must be [broadcastable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html#index-1) numpy arrays.

A **much faster solution**, however, is using `B[list1][:, list2]` as [pointed out by unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610298/7411135). See `In [7]` below.

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
      : import numpy as np
      : 
      : 

In [2]: B = sparse.rand(1000, 1000, .1, format='lil')
      : list1=[1,4,6,8]
      : list2=[2,4]
      : 
      : 

In [3]: arr1 = np.array(list1)[:, None]  # make arr1 a (n x 1)-array
      : arr1
      : 
      : 
Out[3]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [6],
       [8]])

In [4]: arr2 = np.array(list2)[None, :]  # make arr2 a (1 x m)-array
      : arr2
      : 
      : 
Out[4]: array([[2, 4]])

In [5]: %timeit A = B.tocsr()[arr1, arr2]
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit A = B.tocsr()[np.array(list1),:].tocsc()[:,np.array(list2)]
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit B[list1][:, list2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 205 µs per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

slicing happens with this syntax :

```
a[1:4]
```

for a = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), the result is

```
array([2, 3, 4])
```

The first parameter of the tuple indicates the first value to be retained, and the second parameter indicates the first value not to be retained.

If you use lists on both sides, it means that your array has as many dimensions as the lists length.

So, with your syntax, you will probably need something like this :

```
x = A[list1,:,list2]
```

depending on the shape of A.

Hope it did help you.

Comment: The question wasn't about array().